# jQuery capitalization text input

Tags: jquery

I need to create a capatalization jQuery plugin with the following features:

- Auto capitalize every word
- When the user hits backspace, he can still correct the character for example he types "John Mayer" but he decided, "Mayer" should be without capital letter, so he changes it into "mayer" with backspace.

What I tried so far:

```
field.on('keyup change', function(e){
  var val = field.val();

  field.val(val.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }));
});
```

The problem is, regex parses the whole value, but only the new characters typed should be parsed.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why can't you use `strToUpper()` or something similar?

Comment: @PraveenKumar .toUpperCase, but that was not my question, the problem is how could I parse the value each time with the new character instead of using regex / loops and looping through the whole value all the time.

Comment: `strToUpper()` is PHP - he wants JavaScript.

Comment: I would recommend capturing the `input` event as well, and considering `keypress` with a 0ms delay instead of `keyup`.  It just looks more professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, i think it works though i don't seem to get a keycode when i hit backspace on my laptop :S

the idea being that you create an array from the text, manipulate the last word `lword` (last element of array) then place the array as string back into the input box / text area

```
$('input')​.keypress(function(e) {
    var $t = $(this);
        key = e.keyCode,
        txt = $t.val().split(' '),
        lword = txt[(txt.length - 1)];

    function replace() {
        txt[(txt.length - 1)] = lword;
        $t.val(txt.join(' '));
    }

    function undo() {
        lword = lword.toLowerCase();
        replace();
    }

    function capitalize(n) {
        lword = lword.charAt(n).toUpperCase() + lword.slice(n+1);
        replace();
    }

    if (key === 8) {
        undo();
    } else if (key === 32) {
        capitalize(0);
    }

});​​​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/u4pxA/2/)

Comment: I'm sorry for the down vote, but like many similar solutions to similar questions your code is horribly broken.  Consider the following scenario, Alan Nonymous isn't wearing his glasses and starts to fill in a form using this code.  He misreads 'Name:' as 'Surname:' and writes 'Nonymous' in the box. Then, he realizes his error and places the caret at the beginning of the box to type 'Alan '. IIRC, Firefox adapted to accommodate this type of broken code by not resetting the caret position when the value changes, but other browsers don't.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself after some strugling but this is my solution:

```
var doCap = false;

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    var input = $(this);
    var val = input.val();

    if(doCap){
        var lastVal = val.substr(val.length - 1);

        if(lastVal !== " "){
            input.val(val.substring(0, val.length - 1) + lastVal.toUpperCase());
            doCap = false;
        }
    }
});

$('input').keypress(function(e){
    var input = $(this);
    var key = e.keyCode;
    var val = input.val();

    // Capitalize first character ever typed.
    if(val.length === 1){
        input.val(val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1));
    }

    if(key === 32){

        // Prevent double spaces.
        if(val.substr(val.length - 1, 1) === " "){
            return false;
        }

        doCap = true;
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4pxA/4/

Thanks for all the feedback, help.

Answer (score 0):

This works great in Chrome, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work reliably in Firefox. I was able to work up this solution that uses blur instead. Seems to work well across all browsers.

**HTML**

```
<label>Address 1</label>
<input name="addressaddress1" id="addressaddress1" value=""
size="25" />

<label>Address 2</label>
<input name="addressaddress1" id="addressaddress1" value=""
size="25" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.capitalize = function (e) {
    $.each(this, function () {
        if( $('body').data(this.id) != this.value )
        {
            var split = this.value.split(' ');
            for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
                split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
            }
            this.value = split.join(' ');
        }
    });

    return this;
};

$('[id^=address]').on('blur', function (e) {
    $(this).capitalize();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bsegovia/V4ATc/31/

UPDATE!!
This previous solution did not solve for ALL CAPS INPUT. refer to this jsfiddle for the corrected script. http://jsfiddle.net/bsegovia/V4ATc/

Comment: Arggg! I just realized that this doesn't "fix" the field if the user has CAPS lock on...

Answer (score 0):

auto capitalize first world of each world

```
//usage
$("input").keyup(function() {
toUpper(this);
});


//function
function toUpper(obj) {
var mystring = obj.value;
var sp = mystring.split(' ');
var wl=0;
var f ,r;
var word = new Array();
for (i = 0 ; i < sp.length ; i ++ ) {
f = sp[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
r = sp[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
word[i] = f+r;
}
newstring = word.join(' ');
obj.value = newstring;
return true;
}
```